# Play 2.2 Scala: Default values for a simple form

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Currently, I have a simple form that is `Form[(String, String, String)]`

In my scala.html file:

```
    @form(routes.Application.editParticipant(pid)) {
    @inputText(pForm("email"),'_label -> "Email", '_showConstraints -> false, 'placeholder -> email)
    @inputText(pForm("password"),'_label -> "Password", '_showConstraints -> false, 'placeholder -> password)
    @inputText(pForm("phone"),'_label -> "Phone number", '_showConstraints -> false, 'placeholder -> phone)
    <input type="submit" value="edit">
}
```

I want the form to submit the current values of email,password,phone if the user doesn't edit it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass default value like

```
 @inputText(pForm("email").copy(value=Some("abc@def.com")),'_label -> "Email", '_showConstraints -> false, 'placeholder -> email)
```